# How to call "defaultIfEmpty" when list is empty on RxJS?

Tags: rxjs

I've two lists with two distinct objects that need to be converted into the same type, the "second" list will be used only if the "first" list is empty, I tried to use the method `defaultIfEmpty` but it never return the second option.

```
const first = []; // could be [{code: 1}, {code: 2}]
const second = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]

of(first).pipe(
    map((value) => {number: value.code})
).pipe(
    defaultIfEmpty(of(second).pipe(map((value) => {number: value.id})))
).subscribe(doSomething);
```

The desired output is:

```
[{number: 1}, {number: 2}]
```

On the example above, the `map` from `defaultIfEmpty` is never called;

1. how can I "switch" to another method source if the given source is empty?
2. will `subscribe` method be called after the `map` is complete, or it will be called for each item on `map`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**like this ?**

```
const first = []; // could be [{code: 1}, {code: 2}]
const second = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}];

of(first).pipe(
  filter(({length}) => length > 0),
  defaultIfEmpty(second),
  map((arr) => arr.map((x) => ({number: x.code ?? x.id})))
).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: This will not work, it will try to access `length` on the object that only contains the key `code`

Comment: It works, https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-1nxfpd

Comment: `first` is Array, it just filter array.length > 0

Answer (score 1):

If that's an option just create the right observable at runtime:

```js
const makeObservable =
  (arr1, arr2) =>
    from(arr1.length ? arr1 : arr2)
      .pipe(map(({code, id}) => ({number: code ?? id})));
  
const obs1$ = makeObservable([], [{id:1},{id:2}]);
const obs2$ = makeObservable([{code:2},{code:3}], []);

obs1$.subscribe(o => console.log(o));
obs2$.subscribe(o => console.log(o));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@%5E7/dist/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<script>
const {from} = rxjs;
const {map} = rxjs.operators;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const list1: { code: number }[] = [];
const list2 = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }];

of(list1)
  .pipe(
     map((aList) => aList.map((v) => ({ 'number': v.code }))),
     map((listModified) => {
       return listModified?.length > 0
          ? listModified
          : list2.map((value) => ({ number: value.id }));
     })
   )
   .subscribe(console.log);
```

Don't get confused with `map`, one of them is from rxjs, the other is a function for arrays. In your first `map`, you are mapping the the whole array, not each element.

`subscribe` will be called when everything completes within the `pipe`.